# how to use a remote other than origin while hubflow feature start

Tags: git, github, hubflow

I recently forked an open source git(origin) and now the requirement is such that the changes need to be kept private.
While these changes could be pushed to public fork in near future, for now I need to keep them private.

The route I've taken to archive this is by creating a new private repository and adding this as a remote(private).

I want to manage all the new changes in private remote for now. And I'm using **hubflow**.

Now, when I run:

`git hf feature start <feature-name>`

My new branch is created from origin.

So I went ahead and deleted origin branch and let the branch exist only on `private` remote.

Made some changes, created a commit and did:

`git hf push`

The changes were pushed at `private`, but also the branch was created on `origin` and all the changes were pushed.

I want the changes to stay within the `private` repository only.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You might consider changing the URL of origin to reference your private  repository, and adding a new remote named upstream to reference the original repository

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/your/private-repository
git remote add upstream https://github.com/the/original-repository
```

That way, any push to origin would be in your own private repository anyway.

Comment: This is a great approach, I probably would end-up doing this. However I'm more curious if there is a solution to configure Hubflow to archive the same.

Comment: @AnupamJuniwal Since Hubflow is using Git, I suspect it will have an influence.